# How to query or scan nested object/item in DynamoDB using Lambda in node?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to **NO-SQL DB** and wondering how can i query nested **object/item** from table.

I have a controller which passes **`gameId`** and **`teamId`** as `pathParameter`

`/game/RfaIzZ/team/2djTy`

My table looks like this

```
{
  "gameId": "RfaIzZ",
  "name": "Basketball game",
  "teams": {
      "teamOne": {
         "teamId": "2djTy",
         "teamName": "Blue",
         "participants": [{"id": "1", "name": "John"}],
         "score": "10"
      },
      "teamTwo": {
         "teamId": "oiQw5",
         "teamName": "Red",
         "participants": [{"id": "1", "name": "Bob"}],
         "score": "6"
      }
  }
}
```

I want to get teamOne score

how can i do this in AWS Lambda using node

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing for this item `gameId` is the partition key? So when you read a single item, even if you only return some attributes, you pay to read the entire item, there is very little performance gained from only returning the score.

```
const { DynamoDBClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const { DynamoDBDocumentClient, GetCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb");

const client = new DynamoDBClient({ region: "us-west-2" });
const docClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);
const gameId = 'RfaIzZ';

const params = {
  TableName: "my-table",
  Key: {
    'gameId': gameId
  }, 
  ProjectionExpression: 'teams.teamOne.score'
};

const command = new GetCommand(params);

docClient.send(command)
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('Retrieved item:', data.Item);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error retrieving item:', err);
  });
```

Now if you do not know that teamId `2djTy` belongs in `teamOne` then you're best redesigning how you store that object and do so like this, where each object is identified by its `teamId`:

```
  "teams": {
      "2djTy": {
         "teamId": "2djTy",
         "teamName": "Blue",
         "participants": [{"id": "1", "name": "John"}],
         "score": "10"
      },
      "oiQw5": {
         "teamId": "oiQw5",
         "teamName": "Red",
         "participants": [{"id": "1", "name": "Bob"}],
         "score": "6"
      }
  }
```

This would then look like the following:

```
const gameId = 'RfaIzZ';
const teamId = '2djTy'

const params = {
  TableName: "my-table",
  Key: {
    'gameId': gameId
  }, 
  ProjectionExpression: `teams.${teamId}.score`
};
```